# Realized Value, What is it? Does it have a formula?

Tags: probability, statistics

Your class is divided into groups with three members. If X is the random variable representing  the number of males in the group, find its realized values.

Comment: Realized value is an observed value: That is If we have $X$ and $\omega \in \Omega$ then a realized value is $X(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1):

The realized value is the values that your random variable can take:

$$\{0;1;2;3\}$$

each value with a certain probability to be calculated.